# Qt5.5 why isn't error message displayed?

Tags: c++, qt5.5

I'm using Qt5.5 and have written an application, I would like to use QErrorMessage to display an error if encountered during application start up.

I've added:

```
    QErrorMessage errmsg(this);
    errmsg.showMessage("HELLO WORLD");
```

This code has been inserted at the end of my main window constructor, nothing is being displayed, why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the documentation you can read:

> Shows the given message, message, and returns immediately. If the user
>   has requested for the message not to be shown again, this function
>   does nothing.

This means, as soon as the `errmsg` gets destroyed, no messages can be displayed anymore. You have to use the `QErrorMessage` class as member/global variable:

```
this->errmsg = new QErrorMessage(this);
this->errmgs->showMessage("HELLO WORLD");
```

Alternatively, you can use [`QErrorMessage::qtHandler()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qerrormessage.html#qtHandler) - this returns a global instance of the error message handler:

```
QErrorMessage::qtHandler()->showMessage("HELLO WORLD");
```

But if you do that, be aware that QDebug will use this one as well:

> The static qtHandler() function installs a message handler using
>   qInstallMessageHandler() and creates a QErrorMessage that displays
>   qDebug(), qWarning() and qFatal() messages. This is most useful in
>   environments where no console is available to display warnings and
>   error messages.

Comment: Thank you, it may be because my application is terminating, I would like a message displayed to the user as a result of a problem during start-up, the application cannot run.  If the application dies would this prevent the Error message from being displayed?

Comment: Yes, it would. You will have to use `QMessageBox::critical` to do that. This is a blocking call that will wait until the user closes the dialog.